# Localization works in HTML, but not in TS

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome, abp

this might be a silly question, but I couldn't find the reason, please help. Thanks a lot.

Application: FE Core + Angular

The localization is working fine in HTML with abpLocalization and Angular pipe:

```
{{ '::xx' | abpLocalization }}
{{ aNumber | number }}
{{ aDate | date}}
```

But not anymore, when TS code involved.

Some not working examples: (return always english format, no matter which language is selected)

1.

```
console.log('Today is',new Date().toLocaleDateString());
```

2. 

```
this.form = this.fb.group({ abc: [this.decimalNumber],...})

<input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="abc"/>
```

3. 

```
this.form = this.fb.group({ abc: [this.decimalNumber.toLocaleString()],...})

<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="abc"/>
```

and I did map the culture name in CoreModule, what else is missing?

```
CoreModule.forRoot({
      environment,
      registerLocaleFn: registerLocale(
        {
          cultureNameLocaleFileMap: { 
            "DotnetCultureName": "AngularLocaleFileName",
            "de-DE": "de" 
          },
        },
      ),
    }),
```

---

Edit:

I found out that Chrome language setting overrides whatever is selected in the application, after Chrome language was ever changed manually (It was fine before).

And I can't deinstall und reinstall Chrome as it doesn't appear in my list of programs and features.

Edge without any language setting works fine as well.

---

Edit 2:

:/ I thought Edge was working fine, so I ditched Chrome and imported all my bookmarks to Edge, then booooon, Edge is also infected with whatever this is. lol

**The language of browser keeps overriding toLocaleString(), toLocaleDateString()...**

Neither reinstall nor reset broswer setting did help. But it has to have something to do with the broswer settings that I couldnt figure out.

Comment: The 1st option worked for me, maybe it's something on your project?

Comment: @manjirosano I found out that the culture is locked by Chrome Language setting. I set the chrome language to English the other day, since then toLocaleString() only gives english format. If I set the chrome language to another, it is also locked on that, no matter what language I select in the application. Do you know by any chance how can I unlock the Chrome language setting? It was fine before I set it to english.